# What is the difference between &foo::function and foo::function?

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I am using the gtkmm library on linux to draw a simple menu for my GUI.

In the below code the compiler complained about unable to resolve address

```
        sigc::mem_fun(*this, AppWindow::hide)));
                                         ^
appwindow.cpp:15:41: note:   could not resolve address from overloaded function
```

But when I insert the `&` it compiles fine

```
m_menu_app.items().push_back(MenuElem("Quit",
    sigc::mem_fun(*this, &AppWindow::hide)));
```

What difference does it make here? Isn't the `hide` function just an address in the first place?

Comment: One is C++, the other isn't.

Comment: It's a bit inconvenient, but that's just the required syntax.

Comment: The `&` operator returns the address of _something_. In this case it is returning the address of the function so that it can be called at runtime.

Comment: OP is correct in the (implicitly mentioned) fact that for function symbols, as with array symbols, the values of `x` and `&x` are necessarily identical. Perhaps the compiler doesn't "like" the syntax without the `&` when it comes to functions (although, according to the compilation error, it has something to do specifically with the fact that the function is overloaded). In any case, this is a very good question in my opinion.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is the exact definition of the function-to-pointer conversion, [conv.func]:

> An lvalue of function type `T` can be converted to a prvalue of type
>   “pointer to `T`.” The result is a pointer to the function.<sup>55</sup>
>
> ---
>
> <sup>55)</sup> **This conversion never applies to non-static member functions because an lvalue that refers to a non-static member function
>   cannot be obtained**.

Thus the decay that we see with normal, non-member functions<sup>1</sup> doesn't apply and you need to explicitly take the address.

I.e.

```
void f();

struct A {
    void f();
    static void g();
};


auto a = f; // Ok: auto deduced as void(*)()
auto b = A::f; // Error: A::f not an lvalue, auto cannot be deduced
auto c = A::g; // Ok: auto deduced as void(*)()
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Or static member functions.

Comment: The only answer that explains the reasoning behind it.

Comment: Why this was a good idea is another question. The first is for compatibility with C. But why on earth does the standard differentiate between the second and third case (presence of `static`)?

Comment: @abligh Suppose `A::f` did get converted implicitly to a pointer-to-member-function. Then what would happen for `struct B : A { void f() { auto x = A::f; x(); } }`, or even `struct B : A { void f() { A::f(); } }` (the latter currently being perfectly valid C++)? There's a difference between how non-static member functions and static member functions get handled because it's necessary, because non-static member functions are so significantly different from non-member functions and static member functions that treating the same is effectively impossible.

Answer (score 6):

For global (non-member) functions, the name of the function evaluates to the address of that function except when passed to the `&` operator, so you can (for example) assign to a pointer to a function either with or without the `&` equivalently:

```
int f() {}

int (*pf1)() = f;
int (*pf2)() = &f;
```

So, in this case there's really no difference between the two.

For *member* functions<sup>1</sup>, however, the rules are a bit different. In this case, the `&` is required; if you attempt to omit the `&`, the code simply won't compile (assuming a properly functioning compiler, anyway).

There's no particular reason this would have to be the case--it's just how Bjarne decided things should be. If he'd decided he wanted the name of a member function to evaluate to a pointer to a member (equivalent to how things work for non-member functions) he could have done that.

---

<sup>1. Other than static member functions, which mostly act like non-member functions.</sup>

Comment: "There's no particular reason (for) this" is probably the key point in the answer. I would imagine that OP had been asking himself (or herself) exactly that question.

Answer (score 2):

When a function is a non-static member function of a class, then it is necessary to use the form `&ClassName::functionName` when a pointer to the member function is expected in an expression.

When a function is a static member function of a class, both `ClassName::functionName` and `&ClassName;:functionName` can be used when a pointer to a function is expected in an expression.

When a function is a global, i.e. non-member, function, both `functionName` and `&functionName` can be used when a pointer to a function is expected in an expression.